# Jenkins Gradle Plugin - Pass parameters as -P instead of -D

Tags: plugins, parameters, jenkins, gradle, parameter-passing

OK

I have a Jenkins job (Jenkins version more recent).

In my Jenkins job, I have couple of parameters (string type).

Ex: param**1**=value**1** ... to param**N**=value**N**

Now, in Jenkins job, under **BUILD** section, I'm calling "**Invoke Gradle"**.

In this Gradle section, I'm calling a task(s). For ex: *clean build*

What I need is: I want to pass the above Jenkins job's parameters to Gradle as -PparamN=ValueN way?

But when I'm passing -Pparam1=${param1} -Pparam2=${param2} ...and so on in "*Switches*" option in Gradle Build section, I see Jenkins log is showing:

It called Gradle exectuable successfully with the parameters.

```
...somepath.../bin/gradle -Dparam1=value1 -Dparam2=value2 ... -DparamN=valueN -Pparam1=value1 -Pparam2=value2 ... -PparamN=valueN
```

This tell, Jenkins is kind enough to pass the parameters(which I have defined in the job) to Gradle as "-D" way for free.

My ?s:

1. Well, I don't want to pass the above parameters as -Dxxx=yyy
2. I want to pass the parameters only -Pxxx=yyy way
3. Is this possible with using "Invoke Gradle" plugin?

Comment: Well the Jenkins Gradle plugin is simply adding any build parameters as system properties for you. By adding them to the "switches" configuration you are **also** adding them as project properties. I don't see the harm in them being declared twice, and I see no way to disable that particular plugin behavior.

Comment: Agree, but one is defining Java properties (-D) way and other which I'm specifying in "switches" box manually (-P) way are Gradle's system props.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess at this time, there is no way to tell Gradle plugin in Jenkins to NOT pass the parameters (defined in Jenkins job) as -Dxxx=$yyy way (which it's doing for us for free).

We can though, use "switches" box/option to specify these parameters as -P way but it's little confusing how -D parameters will impact the JVM which Gradle uses to run itself and whether -D parameters will somehow clash with -P parameters (as they are getting passed / defined twice).

As a workaround, I stopped using Gradle plugin and used "Execute Shell" option under BUILD section and called gradle executable with the respective parameters (-P way) and task(s).

This is just a plain way of calling Gradle with parameters and tasks like what you'd run at CMD or $ prompt.

Answer (score 5):

As with the Jenkins Gradle plugin 1.27 there is a checkbox to tell the plugin not to pass parameters as system properties and add some parameters manually.
You can also select to pass all parameters as Gradle properties what would be what you probably want.

[image]

Comment: Even when I pass it as Gradle Project Properties, then also it is passing using the parameters using -D instead of -P. Also, if I want to pass multiple parameters (not as project properties), then how can I do that?

Comment: Make sure you are using at least version 1.27 of the Gradle Jenkins Plugin. I added a screenshot above. Note that the configuration for project and system properties is now under "Advanced". There are two fields ("Project properties" and "System properties") which allow you to pass multiple properties.

Answer (score 3):

Let Jenkins have the parameter as -D first. And then you can pass to Gradle with -P. For example, if you have a parameter called env, you can put it in the task as

```
 -Penv=${env}
```

Comment: is there a parameter configuration for gradle plugins in jenkins?